# como obtengo las key me trae la notificacion

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

Esta es mi clase que recibe la notificación como puedo obtener recuperar las `key` que me trae para luego guardarlas automáticamente cuando llegue la notificación

```
  @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        //en este metodo se recibe la notificacion
        String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();
        String a= remoteMessage.getCollapseKey();

        Log.e("DE: ", from);
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null) {
            Log.e("CUERPO", remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

            String p=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitleLocalizationKey();
            System.out.println("prueba_notificaion"+remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitleLocalizationKey());

        showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(), remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e("DATA", "DATA" + remoteMessage.getData());
        String data= String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getData());
        System.out.println("data_data:"+data);

        }
```

Comment: Eso depende de lo que envié el servidor se supone debe ser un objeto json, obtén el valor de "remoteMessage" agregaló a tu pregunta y te digo como obtener los valores.

Comment: buenas tardes @Jorgesys me prodrias decir como ontengo el json es que no se como hacerlo

Comment: Hola natalia buen día aquí, estoy en america, es sencillo puedes realizar debuggin a tu programa agregando un breakpoint, o simplemente impromirlo en la consola o LogCat por ejemplo mediante :  Log.i("NATALIA JSON", "El json es: " + remoteMessage); comenta si tienes duda. @natalia

Answer (score 0):

Los datos del mensaje push se envian como "data" en el objeto [RemoteMessage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage), para accederlo simplemente llama al `remoteMessage.getData()` y eso devuelve un mapa con la información.